# How to color negative estimates in red in stargazer model table?

Tags: r, stargazer

Is it possible to color the font of negative model estimates red in a `stargazer` table in `R`?

The idea is to more easily highlight negative and positive estimates when showcasing a regression model in a table.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend stargazer: https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/comment/dkgw9q1/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3. Use huxtable or gt and/or modelsummary instead. Then your request will become much easier, e.g. in huxtable it's just a call to `map_text_color`.

Comment: Good point. I'll check that out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible with `stargazer` out of the box, but you could write your own functions to accomplish this.

For example, using the LaTeX package `xcolor`, we can create red text with the command `\textcolor{red}{text}`. Since `stargazer` prints negative numbers as `$-$<number>`, we can use the regex `\\$-\\$[0-9]` to find all negative numbers (+ some logic for commas etc.), and wrap them in `\textcolor{red}{text}`.

Here is a working example:

```r
make_red <- function(str) {
  
  paste0(
    "\\textcolor{red}{",
    str,
    "}"
  )
  
}

library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  # Add some negative numbers
  mutate(
    negative_values = -cyl
  ) %>% 
  stargazer::stargazer() %>% 
  stringr::str_replace_all(
    pattern = "\\$-\\$[0-9][.]?[0-9]*",
    replacement = make_red
  ) %>% 
  writeLines()
```

Note that this will print two LaTeX outputs, because `stargaze()` always prints it's output when called. You only need the bottom one.

Remember to add `\usepackage{xcolor}` at the start of your LaTeX document.

The result after compiled LaTeX:

[image: Final result]

Comment: Amazing, thanks!